# drive one application with another

Tags: c++, ms-office

This is a very general question - i'll give you the shortest story that still makes sense -

I'm aware in Microsoft office, you can drive word with excel, or both word and excel with access. What I'm looking for is any guidance you can offer me.

I want to drive an application to automate the tasks that it performs-

I need the developer of that software's permission,
I need any libraries, objects, etc so I can control that program. Can you think of anything else?

What is the best plan of attack? develop something in C++ or continue down the path of writting macros?

Comment: I'd recommend Perl. Is there some reason you want to use C++? Is it just that you're fluent in it? "Writing macros" in what language?

Comment: @Beta I liked C++ and it was what i was using when i first learnt to program, Macros are in visual basic. Thanks for the recommendation, ill get stuck into some research :-)

Comment: Are you looking to drive *any* kind of application or office specifically?

Comment: @greatwolf yes, I am looking to drive any application. I am very keen to learn more about driving any application and the microsoft specific ones too.

Comment: I would take a look at [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) in that case.

Comment: Do you want to control programs that have command-line interfaces, or GUIs?

Comment: @Beta, Currently trying out AutoIT - i like it but can not get it to recognise the window's controls - for example i can get all the controls on windows explorer and write script for that, but cannot get it for the Ultrasonic Program i want to use it on

Comment: @greatwolf, yes these are GUI applications